# webkitRelativePath folder levels

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, webkit

Where can I find info regarding the max number of folder levels the `webkitRelativePath` property can have?

I have this:

```
<input type="file" multiple webkitdirectory id="fileURL" />
```

I add a file `image.jpg` inside `folder6`  `c:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\folder5\folder6\image.jpg` 
but when I debug and set a breakpoint in my for loop when traversing all the files in `folder6`, the `File.webkitRelativePath` returns only the last two folders `"folder5/folder6/image.jpg"`.

```
var files,
    file,
    extension,
    input = document.getElementById("fileURL"),
    output = document.getElementById("fileOutput"),
    holder = document.getElementById("fileHolder");

input.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
    files = e.target.files;
    output.innerHTML = "";

    for (var i = 0, len = files.length; i < len; i++) {
        file = files[i];
        extension = file.name.split(".").pop();
        output.innerHTML += "<li class='type-" + extension + "'>" + file.webkitRelativePath + " (" + Math.floor(file.size / 1024 * 100) / 100 + "KB)</li>";
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Can you include `javascript` at Question ?

Comment: Sure, added some sample js to question.

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the full path to the resource at the clients filesystem ?

Comment: Yes, if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to retrieve the full path to the users filesystem using `input type="file"` elements.

---

- You could package all the files into a single `JSON` file with a "header" document , e.g., `JSON` , describing folder structure to reassemble, parse as `Blob` or .just `JSON`
- Try restructuring "root folder" into a single file containing `data URI` representation of multiple files; with a "header" containing description , for example, in `JSON` , of how to reassemble file structure; see, for example [HTML5 Javascript how to create a gallery photo with all file in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705362/html5-javascript-how-to-create-a-gallery-photo-with-all-file-in-a-folder)
- Include instructions in first file in existing folder; parse for first file , or specific file name on how to reassemble file structure of folder
- Another option would be to substitute `accept="application/zip"` attribute for `multiple` , `directory` attributes; save folder as a `.zip` , which should retain folder structure when decompressed

See also [Exploring the FileSystem APIs](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/)

Comment: How deep can you go?

Comment: Why would you want full path to clients filesystem ? What is the purpose of retrieving the full path to user filesystem resources ?

Comment: I have a predefined folder structure I would like to reuse.

Comment: You could package all the files into a single `JSON` file with a "header" document , e.g., `JSON` , describing folder structure to reassemble, parse as `Blob` or .just `JSON`

Comment: Hm I'm not really sure how that would work. I want to be able to drag and drop a root folder to the input control.

Comment: @PussInBoots _"I want to be able to drag and drop a root folder to the input control"_ You could use `webkitRequestFileSystem` to preserve folder and file structure at user filesystem, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106121/jquery-file-upload-plugin-is-possible-to-preserve-the-structure-of-uploaded-fol/37107246#37107246 . This is also possible using `<input type="file" />` . Can post approach using `<input type="file">` to upload folders if this is requirement