# Load file input with default value

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, input

I am making a blog website and I have a section where the user can edit their posts. I retrieve all the post information from a database and insert it into texareas for editing.

However, I don't know how I can load the file inputs with the uploaded images. For example, all uploaded images are stored in a folder, `uploads`, and I want to reference that, so that they don't have to upload that file each time they make a change.

I guess it should look something like:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" value="uploads/[NAME OF IMAGE]">
```

Comment: you cannot. You just leave the file input and the user uploads a new file that in turn is updated in datbase

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106121/jquery-file-upload-plugin-is-possible-to-preserve-the-structure-of-uploaded-fol/ , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634049/how-to-print-all-the-txt-files-inside-a-folder-using-java-script/